# date discrepancy in zoo package when setting origin

Tags: r, date, zoo

When I try `as.Date(42010, origin = "1900-01-01")` or `as.Date.numeric(...)` from `zoo` package in R; it returns Jan 8 2015 instead of Jan 6, while I can change the origin back by 2 days to sort this, wonder why is this issue coming up.

Comment: Why do you think it should be `Jan 6`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @akrun I wonder why you expect Jan 6 to be the outcome. I checked with base R and various online calendars that there are 42010 days between 2015-01-08 and 1900-01-01:

```
as.Date("2015-01-08") - as.Date("1900-01-01")
## Time difference of 42010 days
```

Note also that this has nothing to do with the `zoo` package. The `as.Date.numeric` function in `zoo` and base R differ only in the default value for `origin`. While the authors in the R Core Team argue that it is unreasonable to give a default, the `zoo` package has chosen to use the same default as the `as.numeric.Date` function (i.e., 1970-01-01). Therefore, the outcome is the same no matter whether base R's or `zoo`'s `as.Date` function is used:

```
base::as.Date(42010, origin = "1900-01-01")
## [1] "2015-01-08"
zoo::as.Date(42010, origin = "1900-01-01")
## [1] "2015-01-08"
```

Comment: @arun  - excel converts jan 6 '15 to 42010 and it has an origin of 1/1/1900 hence the problem. since my input is a xlsx files converted to csv it is now a problem..

Comment: Maybe export the columns with dates to characters rather than integers in the csv. That should be less ambiguous...